# Extracting contours in OpenCV, c++

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

How can get the all contours of segmented image,I'm trying to get contours in borders of image but its not getting

[Output from drawContours()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWwCT.png)

How can extract border contours

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE7Ks.png)

Comment: it seems to work pretty well, what's your expected output?

Comment: I need each and every segment contours separately with the borders

Comment: Can you sketch an image with the expected output? It's not clear what you need.